# Xenocode Postbuild and RemoteSoft's Salamander: Experiences? Preferences?

Tags: .net

One of my client's requirements is that the product be distributed without the need for other installations - e.g. .net.

After research I have found Xenocode's Postbuild and RemoteSoft's Salamander.  Both seem to do what I need.  Has anyone here used either of these tools and will you share your experiences?  Can you compare the costs?

Xenocode is asking me for details of my product before providing me with a price, which gives me a great deal of pause.  Are there hidden costs?

Comment: I ended up with Xenocode.  RemoteSoft, at this time, does not support the latest .Net

Comment: Do you mean the 3.x or the 4.x? What about targeting 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Xenocode no longer supports PostBuild, they have moved into the application virtualisation space with their "Spoon" product. Salamander is no longer maintained either. Consider RedGate SmartAssembly or LogicNP CryptoObfuscator. Both of these products are actively maintained and support VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

Comment: Just a week ago today (on June 30) I purchased an upgrade to PostBuild 2010.  Although I am not sure that it supports .NET 4.0.

I will have a look at those two products - thanks for posting them!

Comment: Nice. I got this in an email from them yesterday (July 8) in response to a query about my upgrade options: "At this time we do not offer a product with the features of Postbuild." I'd be interested to know what you end up doing, I'm currently evaluating both products myself.

Comment: Boinst, I know this is very old - my apologies for missing this. In any case, Spoon did what I needed it to and that is what I'm using at this time.  However, I'm going to give Crypto another look, mostly due to pricing.